# Angular material md-select empty value validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-select

In md-select, I have added an empty md-option item and this select field is a required field. But Validation is not working when I selected 'Choose One' item with value as empty.

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygrJLG

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" layout="column" layout-align="center center" layout-padding="" class="selectdemoValidations" ng-app="MyApp">
  <form name="myForm">

    <div layout="row" layout-align="start" flex="">
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Favorite Color</label>
        <md-select name="favoriteColor" ng-model="favoriteColor" required="" >
          <md-option value=''>Choose One</md-option>
          <md-option ng-value=color ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color}}</md-option>         
        </md-select>
        <div class="errors" ng-messages="myForm.favoriteColor.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div layout="row" layout-align="start">
      <md-checkbox ng-model="myForm.$invalid" disabled="">Form Invalid</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="myForm.$dirty" disabled="">Form Dirty</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="myForm.$submitted" disabled="">Form Submitted</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="myForm.favoriteColor.$touched" disabled="">Select Touched</md-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div layout="row" layout-align="end" flex="">
      Selected Color is {{favoriteColor}}
      <md-button ng-click="clearValue()" ng-disabled="!favoriteColor">Clear</md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="save()" class="md-primary">Save</md-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with that:

```
$scope.$watch('favoriteColor', function(val)
{
    if (!val) $scope.favoriteColor = null;
});
```

Why? Because there is a difference between `null` and `undefined`:

null = the value set to empty value

undefined = the value has not been initialized

Answer (score 0):

just make the 'Choose One' option disabled with:

```
 <md-option ng-value disabled>Choose One</md-option>
```

Comment: I should have to allow the user to select 'Choose One' and then show the error validation message.